# How to pass parameters using flask in array form

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

Using flask i am hitting the razorpay api in this way given below :

```
    virtualAccUrl = 'https://'+str(current_app.config.get('RAZORPAY_ID'))+':'+str(
        current_app.config.get('RAZORPAY_SECRET_ID'))+'@api.razorpay.com/v1/virtual_accounts'

    virtual_payload = {
        "receivers": {
            "types": [
                "qr_code"
            ],
            "amount": 200,
            "qr_code": {
                "name": "Store_1",
                "fixed_amount": 'true',
                "payment_amount": 30000,
                "customer_id": "CUS158022319",
                "notes": {
                        "purpose": "Test UPI QR code notes"
                }
            },
            "description": "Test UPI QR description",
            "notes": {
                "purpose": "Test UPI QR notes"
            }
        },
        "amount_expected": 100
    }
    virtual_response = requests.post(url=virtualAccUrl, params=virtual_payload)
    virtual_response = json.loads(virtual_response.content)
    print('111111111111111')
    print(virtual_response)
```

Biut it is returning me the error like :

> {'error': {'code': 'BAD_REQUEST_ERROR', 'description': 'The receivers
> must be an array.', 'source': 'business', 'step':
> 'payment_initiation', 'reason': 'input_validation_failed', 'metadata':
> {}, 'field': 'receivers'}}

Can anyone please suggest me ?? how we can send the data using flask in api in array form . i am stuck here . i dont know how to solve this error . i am a newbe in flask thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per the response "receivers" key's value must be an array whwereas you are passing dictionary. Try enclosing that value in list as
`"receivers":[your_previous_value]`

It would be better if you can share the api documentation you are reffering.

Comment: i tried this but it didnt work and i am or code generate from https://razorpay.com/docs/api/smart-collect/ link.

Comment: Have you tried using razorpay's python client? https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/server-integration/python/. It also has an sample flask app code.

Comment: Hello @Codographer i am doing the same as in my code as you can see on my code .. but getting error